# MongoError: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am trying to connect my node server with mongodb with ssl options enabled.

## mongod.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
  enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: XX
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,XXX.XX.XX.XXX
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/PEMKEYFILE.pem
    PEMKeyPassword: "PASSWORDFORPEM"
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem

security:
  authorization: enabled

replication:
  oplogSizeMB: 1024
  replSetName: "REPLSET"
```

## node server conf file

```
MONGO_URL: '<pathToMongoDb>/<db>',
        MONGO_REPLICA_SET_READ_PREFERENCE: 'nearest',
        MONGO_REPLICA_SET: {
            ssl: true,
            sslValidate: true,
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCa: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem'),
            replicaSet: 'REPLSET',
            auto_reconnect: false,
            poolSize: 24,
            socketOptions: {
                keepAlive: 1000,
                connectTimeoutMS: 30000
            }
        },
        MONGO_SERVER: {
            ssl: true,
            sslValidate: false,
            checkServerIdentity: false,
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem'),
            sslCA: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem'),
            poolSize: 24,
            socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 },
            reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            reconnectInterval: 1000
        },
        MONGO_CHECK_SERVER_IDENTITY: false,
```

## mongoose file

```
mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URL,{
  db: {
      native_parser: true,
      readPreference: config.MONGO_REPLICA_SET_READ_PREFERENCE
  },
  server: config.MONGO_SERVER,
  replset: config.MONGO_REPLICA_SET,
  user: config.MONGO_USER,
  pass: config.MONGO_PASSWORD,
  auth: {
      authdb: config.MONGO_AUTHDB
  }
```

})

I have created the CA certificate and and signing certificate but the node server is returning me with the error :

> MongoError: failed to connect to server [XX.XXX.XXX.XX:port] on first connect
>
> MongoError: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I am able to connect to the mongo using shell using the following command

```
mongo XX.XX.XX.XXX:XX/<db> -u <user> -p <pass> --authenticationDatabase=admin --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/PEMKEYFILE.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/CAFILE.pem --sslAllowInvalidHostnames`
```

Have asked the same question on SO but was told to post it here as peple here might help.
Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you gone through this http://demarcsek92.blogspot.qa/2014/05/mongodb-ssl-setup.html

Comment: How did you create the file `/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem`? Is it self signed? You were connecting using a different certificate in the shell (`/etc/ssl/PEMKEYFILE.pem`)

Comment: yes it is self signed and i am using same file but by mistake here i wrote different names

Comment: When you say "self signed", what do you mean? Is the key `PEMKEYFILE.pem` self-signed? How did you create this file?